# Cant find a path to java.exe to start SonarQube

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sonarqube

Here is the path to `StartSonar` batch file:

```
C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-9.7.1.62043\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
```

And here is my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin
```

I use the same path to setup `SONAR_JAVA_PATH` environment variable but all I get is:

```
Starting SonarQube...
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I experimented with different paths to `java.exe` file, but nothing was working.

Here is the directory content of bin file in `JAVA_HOME` path:

```
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 appletviewer.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 extcheck.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 idlj.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            41.216 jabswitch.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 jar.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 jarsigner.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 java-rmi.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56           276.224 java.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 javac.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 javadoc.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56           157.440 javafxpackager.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 javah.exe
13.10.2021.  10:56            20.224 javap.exe
//other exe files related to jdk
```

You see that there is `java.exe` file here, so I really don't know where to go from here.

I did restart `cmd` after setting env variable.

As requested, here is the output from this commandline, `@For %G In (java StartSonar.bat) Do @Echo %~$PATH:G`, entered within my working Command Prompt window:

```
StartSonar.bat was unexpected at this time.
```

The output of commandline `Path`:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\pk\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\pk\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\pk\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
```

Comment: You have not explained the method(s) you have used to define your environment variables. I would also expect you to [Edit] your question to submit the output from this commandline, ```@For %G In (java StartSonar.bat) Do @Echo %~$PATH:G```, entered within your working Command Prompt window.

Comment: Only one method: I searched for every path where java.exe file can be found. That means oracle dir, jre and jdk and System32 paths. Replaced the path of env variable and restarted cmd for every replacement but got same result every time. I edited the question and provided the output

Comment: That output does not reflect the expected result of the code I wrote. Also you have not told us how you defined those variables, which is crucial to our understanding. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `Path`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, then paste the output into your question, when you update it with that missing crucial information.

Comment: Output is in the edit. I also used set command `set PATH=C:\new\path` .

Comment: @Compo Still here?

Comment: Your PATH output is wrong, there are several very important locations missing from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary post, not an answer. I have submitted it, only to assist you to fix your `PATH` environment variable.

Open the GUI for your environment variables, starting with the **System** environment, delete everything in the box. Now repopulate it with the following, exactly as below, in the same order.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH
%ProgramFiles%\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
%SystemDrive%\msys64\mingw64\bin
%ProgramFiles%\nodejs
%ProgramFiles%\dotnet
%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin
%ProgramFiles%\Git\cmd
%ProgramFiles%\Azure Data Studio\bin
%ProgramFiles%\PostgreSQL\14\bin
%ProgramFiles%\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\bin
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn
```

Now switch to the **User** environment, delete everything in the box, then repopulate it with the following, exactly as below, in the same order.

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps
%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
%UserProfile%\.dotnet\tools
%LocalAppData%\GitHubDesktop\bin
```

Now, in your new cmd.exe instances, you should have your environment uncorrupted, and containing the correct/wanted paths.